# Get post from facebook page via graph api and post it on other page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to get posts from pages feed and post it on other page like 
Get post from Ladbible page and post it on my page

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Execute GET 
`graph.facebook.com/theladbible/feed?fields=id&access_token=ACCESSTOKEN`

That will give you a list of posts. eg

```
data: [
{
created_time: "2018-01-26T01:20:00+0000",
message: "This is so heartwarming ❤️ ELLE",
id: "199098633470668_4420027538044402"
},
{
created_time: "2018-01-26T00:45:00+0000",
message: "It was the Twitter equivalent of a Rock Bottom and the 
People's Elbow ",
id: "199098633470668_4420692437977912"
}]
```

You will be looking at the ID field which is in the form `pageid_postid`. You just want the post id so trim the page id_ to be left with just postid.

Then execute POST

`graph.facebook.com/yourpageid/feed?link=https://www.facebook.com/ladbible/posts/POSTID&access_token=PAGEACCESSTOKEN`

and that will result in you "sharing" the post from ladbible to your page.